# Updating and sharing a variable between 3 classes

Tags: android, variables, inheritance, aggregation

**Edit** I've tried to make my question clearer.

I have a MyGLRendering class as below in which I have a method from which I do all my logic updating.  As you can see I'm accessing my sprite's X co-ordinate through an object I created.  So my 'x' variable resides within my Sprite class.

All I want to do is move the code from my update method into it's own class.  There call it from my rendering method.

```
public class MyGLRenderer extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    Sprite sprite1;
    public MyGLRenderer() {
        sprite1 = new Sprite();
     }


    //Now I can access and update the X variable from from this class like so:

    public void LogicUpdate() {
        sprite1.X = 0;   //I update all my sprites positions here - I want to move all this code into it's own class
    }
}
```

}

If I try to move my code to a new class, I just can't access the variable like so above.

```
sprite1.X = 0;
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: If you are initializing variables in the constructor and not changing them later, it is always a good idea to add the `final` modifier. Thus, unless you intentionally assign `null`, the compiler will complain of uninitialized vars.
Could you clean up your code a bit, name classes and variables according to conventions and explain what 'meanwhile, back in my Renderer Class' means?

Comment: Hi @ohaleck, I'm not doing this, I'm declaring variables outside of the constructor and initialising them (ie, assigning something to them) in the constructor.  I've changed my class names as suggested.  Also when I say 'meanwhile, back in my Renderer Class' simply means that after I've made my Logic class, I'm then changing my code in my rendering (MyGLRenderer) class from it's original format (ie, removing the logic updates and trying to now access them via the object I've created). Thanks :-)

Comment: Of course that is what I meant, sorry. Making the variables final should help you find out what you are doing wrong (because it seems quite messy to me).

Comment: You're certainly correct that's it's messy!  All I'm trying to do is move my updateLogic method out of my MyGLRenderer class and into my Logic class.  I'm doing this because my MyGLRenderer class is quite simply getting too big and I need to move some code out of it to make it more manageable.  If you have an alternative suggestion, it would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: PS I'm not sure what you mean by making my variables static, if I do that then I can't update them/change their values.

Comment: declaring a variable `static` only means that there is 1 instance of this variable per class instead of 1 instance of the variable per object instance (it is a **class variable**, not an **instance variable**). You can still update/change them. You seem to be confusing the keywords `final` and `static`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Final, you advised to change my variables to final.

Comment: Yes, I meant final. It helps keep the state of the application in good shape. If you mean to assign a variable only once, you should do it as you declare it or in the constructor. If you make the variable final, the compiler makes sure that you haven't missed the initialization.
That said, you can either follow Vishal's suggestion to have one static shared object to keep your variables (but it might not be thread safe), or you can pass the shared variables to constructors of the objects you create.

Comment: Thanks - nothing is working unless I use statics which I don't really want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Sprite.java
public class Sprite {
    int spriteX; // this will implicitly set 0 here

    void setX(int newX) {
        this.spriteX = newX;
    }
}

// Logic.java
public class Logic {
    final MyGLRenderer renderer;
    public Logic(MyGLRenderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    void update() {
        this.renderer.sprite1.setX(1);
    }
}

// MyGLRenderer.java
// IMHO it is not a good idea to have the Activity implement Renderer, but that's 
// whole another story
public class MyGLRenderer extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    final Sprite sprite1;
    public MyGLRenderer() {
        sprite1 = new Sprite();
    }
}
```

With the code above, in order to create an object of the `Logic` class, you need to pass `MyGLRenderer` to it. It has a reference to a `Sprite` object which is made available to `Logic`. Now calling `update()` on `Logic` will update the value of `spriteX` in your `Sprite` instance.
The above code will work *only* if all of these classes are in the same package. If they are not, you need to declare the `Logic.renderer` and `MyGLRenderer.sprite1` fields, as well as the `Sprite.setX` method, static.

Comment: Man, this is awesome, it's actually working and I can now de-clutter my main rendering class - thank you for this @ohaleck it's a great help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create one static class, put renderer object inside it & make all other classes to access this renderer object.

SomeStaticClass Class ->

```
public class SomeStaticClass{

    public static SomeClass objectToShare; // You can also have getter & setter, getter will always check if objectToShare is initialized or not, so that it will prevent NPE

    public static SomeClass getObjecctToShare() {
         if(objectToShare != null){
              return objectToShare;
         }
         //Init objectToShare here
         return objectToShare;
    }
}
```

Now in other classes (Let's say Logic Class)->

```
SomeStaticClass.getObjectToShare().something = something;
```

Comment: Hi @VishalPawale - thanks for this, it sound like something which would work - could I please ask you to edit your answer with a code example (even Pseudo code would be good) - thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this code, it's a public class but with a static constructor?  Does doing this mean that I will need to make all of my variables static?  could you exapand on this and maybe show how I can implement this in relation to my code?  In my code which class is this 'static' class replacing?

Comment: No dude, create one separate class(in above code its "SomeStaticClass", name is bit confusing as its not a static class), now put the variable which you want to share in this class as a static variable (in above code its "objectToShare"), and in other classes access this variable directly using "SomeStaticClass.objectToShare".

Actually I'm not understanding which variable you want to share (renderer)?If yes, then put renderer as static variable inside some new class, and access it from other classes ("Logic" & others)like->

`SomeNewClass.renderer`

Comment: No, renderer is just an instance of my MyGLRenderer class as shown above.  I want to share the Sprite1.x variable which resides in the Sprite class and I'm accessing through my sprite1 object.  I've tried this but I have 2 problems.  I'm still getting a nullPointerException and also I can't put the object initialisation within the static method as I it needs to run on the UI thread.  I'm putting it into the constructor as I'm creating the object in my MyGLRenderer class within runOnUiThread(new Runnable().

Comment: If I have to change all of my variables (and there are lot of them!) to static, isn't this bad and to be avoided?

Comment: No dude, I'm not saying to make all vars. static, just make the one which is needed

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand, but isn't it bad practice to have static variables? I mean aren't they held in memory for the entire life of the app. Is there no other option to achieve what I'm after?  Thanks

Comment: Yess.They are held in memory for entire life of app but I think this is the best way to solve the problems like this.

Is your problem solved?

Comment: I've gone with ohalek's anwer @VishalPawale but thanks so much for your time, I really appreciate it.